# ExpandableListViewAdapter can't override getItemViewType

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I have a class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter.

> public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

In the listview my items are reused, and I'd like to prevent that.

I've learned that using IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE would prevent the OS to reuse them, but I have to use it in the getItemViewType method.

When I added this code:

```
@Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 0;
  }
```

I have the following error:

> Method does not override method from its superclass.

How can I use the setting to prevent my ExpandableList to reuse items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Method does not override method from its superclass.

That's happening because a `BaseExpandableListAdapter` doesn't share the same interface as a `BaseAdapter` so that method is not available to be overriden. `BaseExpandableListAdapter` does expose a similar mechanism for view types but it's divided between the group and child view types so you need to override one(or all) of the methods below to modify the view type handling system:

> [getChildType(int groupPosition, int childPosition)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildType%28int,%20int%29) - view type for child rows
>
> [getGroupType(int groupPosition)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupType%28int%29) - view type for group rows

For:

> I've learned that using IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE would prevent the OS to
>   reuse them

No, it doesn't, it just tells the adapter that the type of view reused doesn't matter. If you want to stop the view reuse then simply create a new row view in the `getChildView()` and/or `getGroupView()`(so no `if (convertView == null)...` code in there). This has an impact on performance, however.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. Unfortunately I couldn't use the "default" ignoring so I created a custom logic for handling the getChildView and I managed to accomplish what I wanted.